# Blender Stereoscopy, What glasses

Tags: 3d-view

I see that blender supports [Steroscopy](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Dfelinto/Stereoscopy) in the viewport. What kind of modes are there and which glasses are needed. I am not sure if this is considered off-topic but it is useful to know nevertheless.

**Display Modes:**

- Anaglyph
- Interlace
- V-Interlace
- Side-by-Side
- Quad-Buffer

[image]

Comment: Could it be that this feature is not in 2.68?

Comment: not in a official release

Comment: "Anaglyph" generally implies red-cyan.

Comment: I would guess that one should use [red-cyan Anaglyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D) glasses with this. (BTW, is this the [Multiview branch](http://www.dalaifelinto.com/?p=843)?)

Comment: what about active shutter glasses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is not officially in Blender yet, but probably the behavior will not change when it is added.

With a regular monitor, only Anaglyph will give you the 3D effect, and for that you would use the typical red-cyan anaglyph glasses.

The other display modes are meant for 3D monitors or projectors, and you would pick the display mode that works for your device. Those devices would come with the appropriate glasses if they are needed.

Comment: I wonder if will make modeling easier. Editing 3d in 3d!

Comment: Please update this discussion- While felantai has been working with steady results on Multibranch, I'm still unsure if quad-buffered is supported there. Yes, I DO expect that editing in stereo would greatly enhance modeling!